# Automatically "Accept this solution" when there are unmet dependencies during installation

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, vagrant

Is there a way to automatically accept the suggested solution when installing packages with `apt-get`? I am playing around with Vagrant and am trying to automate installing some libraries with a shell script that runs after provisioning.

Occasionally some packages need a little help in order to install properly. For example, I might see something like the message below:

```
==> default: The following actions will resolve these dependencies:
==> default: 
==> default:      Remove the following packages:
==> default: 1)     libcurl4-openssl-dev        
==> default: 2)     libssl-dev                  
==> default: 3)     node-gyp                    
==> default: 4)     nodejs-dev                  
==> default: 5)     npm                         
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

Installation halts right here (or sometimes aborts) because I can't interact with it.

I know you can use `apt-get install -y whatever` to automatically answer yes to messages asking if you want to continue, but that doesn't seem to affect prompts like these.

Comment: That looks like `aptitude` not `apt`.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Sorry, I get the two confused. I'll update the question.

Comment: `apt-get` and `apt` are basically the same. However, I'm talking about `aptitude`, which is a separate package managing script. neither `apt` nor `apt-get` has that prompt you have in your question, but `aptitude` does.